# Compare two columns and output new column based on order of reference column

Tags: excel, python-3.x

I'm trying to compare two columns (list) with same IDs (just in different order). I want to reference first columns order, compare it to the next column, and then reformat 2nd columns order based on first columns order in new column (or list). From there I can pull corresponding columns that match the order of first column (price, demographic, etc).

Input:

First column (reference column):

```
12321
12323
324214
32313452
1232132
fs2421
sfasrfas
asfasd
```

Second column (re-order necessary):

```
12321
sfasrfas
12323
324214
1232132
fs2421
asfasd
32313452
```

I have tried writing a for loop in python with two separate lists for each column IDs as well as Index/Match in excel but can only seem to output 'matching' IDs.

Excel

```
=INDEX($A$2:$A$589,MATCH(C2,$A$2:$A$589,0),2)
```

Python

```
## setting empty list and extract only matched values from both lists made above ##
matched_IDs = []
unique_IDs = []
for Part_No in updated_2_list:
    if Part_No in updated_1_list:
        matched_IDs.append(Part_No)
    elif Part_No not in updated_2_list:
        unique_IDs.append(Part_No)
print(matched_IDs)
#len(matched_IDs)
len(matched_IDs)
```

I expect to match the order of first column in new column (or list). 
Output:

Third column (new column after second column was re-ordered)

```
12321
12323
324214
32313452
1232132
fs2421
sfasrfas
asfasd
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean like this:

```
=INDEX(C:C,MATCH(A1,C:C,0))
```

[image]

Comment: Essentially yes, but I want to take the order of column A, and implement same order to column C (in either a new column or just change order in column C). Also thanks for changing format thats easier to read.

Comment: Then change the `D:D` to `C:C`

Comment: That did not work unfortunately, I want column your C to match exactly column A (based on order from row 1-8). That make sense?

Comment: Awesome! Sorry I had a typo! Thank you so much! Now I just need to figure out how to write a script to do the exact same thing in python! Thanks!